# Background image shrinking after zoom in followed by screen rotation and zoom out

Tags: html, css, screen-orientation

I've noticed a bug on a site I am building. When you zoom in on a mobile phone, then rotate the screen orientation and then zoom out the background shrinks and only returns to the original size when the screen is rotated again. Any idea where I am going wrong?

Here is the CSS I am using:

```
html { 
background: url(images/scroll.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
min-height: 100%;
}
```

Cheers

Comment: I believe it is that the mobile client is redrawing the whole page when the orientation is changed, but not so on zoom. Not sure how to fix that for you.

Comment: Hey @philtune I think that's the problem, but I've no idea how to resolve it. Hopefully someone can assists.

Comment: I've never used `cover` before, so I don't know of its quirks, but I wonder if it is a mix of that and using `background-position: fixed` that is messing it up.

Comment: @philtune simply removing fixed fix the problem, HA! Thanks for helping we take a step back from a problem that I thought was more severe.

Answer (score 1):

Simply removing fixed prior to using cover resolved this problem.

```
background: url(images/scroll.jpg) no-repeat center center;
```